# How to change the height of a vertical line on the page as you scroll by it

Tags: javascript, css

I created a vertical line on my webpage, and want the line to grow/shrink as the user scrolls by it. Right now the line is just staying the same height the entire time. If you look at this website, https://robbowen.digital/ a good example of what I would like is shown. I have been looking into parallax but can't quite seem to figure it out. Can anyone help? Is this something simple that can be implemented? Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/atrain42/pen/OJQLPqx

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="vertical"></div>
      <header>
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </header>

      <section>
        <h1>section 01</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

CSS:

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    z-index: 1;
}
header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 5rem;
}

section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(235, 198, 245);
    z-index: 1;
}

section h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.vertical {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    height: 40rem;
    z-index: 2;
    color: black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any growing/shrinking vertical line in your example

Comment: I am trying to implement this affect @Prana

Answer (score 0):

You can do so adding an event listener to scroll and set the height of div according to the scroll value, take a look:

```
const verticalLine = document.getElementById("vertical")

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // use division by two to limit the height size
  scrollPosition = window.scrollY / 2 ;
  // set the current scroll position as the height of div
  verticalLine.style.height = `${lastKnownScrollPosition}px`
});
```

See the [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/yago-biermann/pen/gOvYpQd)

Comment: I will give this a  try shortly @Yago Biermann

Comment: Works great, you are a genius! @Yago